# sudo chef-client displays no runlist for oracle_rdbms, hence does not install oracle

Tags: chef-infra

Created a new VM centos7 based , installed chef on it

Created an environment DEMOKMOCK-hvm

```
knife search "role:oracle_rdbms AND chef_environment:DEMOKMOCK-hvm"
1 items found

Node Name:   el2-KMOCK-idb1
Environment: DEMOKMOCK-hvm
FQDN:
IP:          10.103.130.54
Run List:    role[oracle_rdbms]
Roles:       oracle_rdbms
Recipes:
Platform:    centos 7.2.1511
Tags:

knife environment edit DEMOKMOCK-hvm
```

displays a JSON which has all the cookbooks with right versions

Added the node el2-KMOCK-idb1 to this environment

```
knife node edit el2-KMOCK-idb1

{
  "name": "el2-KMOCK-idb1",
  "chef_environment": "DEMOKMOCK-hvm",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [

    ]
  },
  "run_list": [
  "role[oracle_rdbms]"
]

}
```

If we look at role chefrepo/roles/oracle_rdbms.json

```
{
  "name": "oracle_rdbms",
  "description": "",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "default_attributes": {
  },
  "override_attributes": {
  },
  "chef_type": "role",
  "run_list": [

  ],
  "env_run_lists": {
  }
}
```

Now when i run sudo chef-client i get no runlist for oracle_rdbms

```
sudo chef-client

INFO: Forking chef instance to converge
Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.2

INFO: *** Chef 11.12.2 ***
INFO: Chef-client pid: 28090
INFO: Run List is [role[oracle_rdbms]]
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to []
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for el2-KMOCK-idb1
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Object Not Found:
resolving cookbooks for run list: []
[2016-07-27T02:17:19+00:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks []
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources
[2016-07-27T02:17:20+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.146990597 seconds

Running handlers:
[2016-07-27T02:17:20+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
Running handlers complete

[2016-07-27T02:17:20+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 1.660708561 seconds
```

Comment: Double check your knife and chef-client are using the same Chef Server URL. They might be pointed at different orgs.

Comment: Did you actually upload the role file to the same chef server with `knife`?  What does `knife role show oracle_rdbms` return?

Comment: Obviously your expanded runlist is empty, your node runlist is made of just a role, and this role runlist is empty, so there's no cookbook to load an execute. Exactly what the lines 8 and 9 of your log show. Add a cookbook::recipe in your role runlist.

Comment: `knife role show oracle_rdbms
chef_type:           role
default_attributes:
description:
env_run_lists:
json_class:          Chef::Role
name:                oracle_rdbms
override_attributes:
run_list:`

Comment: That's your problem.  The role run list is empty.  You need to add recipes or other defined roles.